# Is there a way to search the blockchain by mixin?

Tags: ringsize, blockchain-data

Is there a tool that I can use to search the blockchain for transactions sorted by number of mixins?

For example if I wanted to find all transactions with exactly 10 mixins how would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to write some code for this.

There is a BlockchainDB::for_all_transactions function which can run a callback through all the transactions in the db. See the blockchain_dump.cpp file for an example. The callback can simply output the hash for all the transactions with a mixin of 10 (mixin being one less than the number of inputs in each vin array element). Note that those elements don't necessarily have to have the same size (ie, inputs can have different mixins).

Comment: If someone wrote code to do this in the way you describe would it weaken the privacy of those who happen to choose very unusual mixin amounts? For example if a 33 year old always used a mixin of 33 (and nobody else did the same) how would that impact the users privacy?

Comment: Yes, this is a known data leak, and a reason why mixins may end up quantized in the future (but no concrete plans on that at the moment). Also, the coming GUI will not expose actual mixin by default, just a "high/medium/low" privacy level, IIRC, mitigating this for now.